# How to pass data from android module to flutter module in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I have successfully integrated flutter module in my native android application by following [steps here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/android/add-flutter-screen?tab=default-activity-launch-java-tab) .

The process of caching flutter engine I have already done in Application class. I am launching my flutter screen  with this from android fragment.

```
startActivity(
      FlutterActivity
        .withCachedEngine("my_engine_id")
        .build(currentActivity)
      );
```

Now I want to pass my `auth token` to flutter module for making api calls.

I am following the process from [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/flutter-for/android-devs#how-do-i-handle-incoming-intents-from-external-applications-in-flutter) and created method channel in dart code but I do not know where to create the `method channel` in the native side.

If I am creating it in `project/moduleName/.android/app/src/main/java/com/package/host/MainActivity.java`

It is giving exception `Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method`

Also note that this folder is placed in `.gitignore`  by default when I created this flutter module in Android studio.

I already has a look at older tutiorals but this caching of flutter engine option is not there in them.

Please tell where am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a reference for the Flutter Engine and then use it to create the Method Channel. Take in account that the activity/fragment that launch the Flutter activity is in charge to manage the Method Channel.

```
private const val FLUTTER_ENGINE_ID = "flutter_engine"
private const val CHANNEL = "myApp.flutter.dev/auth"

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(R.layout.activity_main) {

    private lateinit var flutterEngine: FlutterEngine

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setupFlutterEngine()
        setupMethodChannel()
        setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar))

        fab.setOnClickListener {
            launchFlutterModule()
        }
    }

    private fun setupFlutterEngine() {
        createAndConfigureFlutterEngine()
        FlutterEngineCache
            .getInstance()
            .put(FLUTTER_ENGINE_ID, flutterEngine)
    }

    private fun createAndConfigureFlutterEngine() {
        flutterEngine = FlutterEngine(this)
        flutterEngine.dartExecutor.executeDartEntrypoint(DartExecutor.DartEntrypoint.createDefault())
    }

    private fun setupMethodChannel() {
        MethodChannel(
            flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger,
            CHANNEL
        ).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
            // All your implementation for auth token
        }
    }

    private fun launchFlutterModule() {
        startActivity(getFlutterIntent())
    }

    private fun getFlutterIntent(): Intent {
        return FlutterActivity
            .withCachedEngine(FLUTTER_ENGINE_ID)
            .backgroundMode(FlutterActivityLaunchConfigs.BackgroundMode.transparent)
            .build(this)
    }
}
```

You can make a `Wrapper` where you can hold the method channel code and flutter engine setup, and this wrapper is init in your `Application` class or maybe init and injected with `Dagger` or `Hilt` where is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass simple data as request parameters.
Android code:

```
FlutterActivity
    .withNewEngine()
    .initialRoute("/MyPage?username=my_user&age=30&gender=male")
    .build(MainActivity.this)
```

Flutter code, I use [GetX](https://pub.dev/packages/get) library to get the parameters

```
Map<String, String?> parameters = Get.parameters;
print("parameters: $parameters");
```

Output:

```
parameters: {username: my_user, age: 30, gender: male}
```

Comment: Hi, I called Get.parameters but it is empty. Where I need to call it?

Comment: @TúlioCalazans any where in '/MyPage'. You need to register '/MyPage' in getPages first.

Answer (score 0):

- First create flutter platform client with channel
- set methodCallHamdler passing same channel
  Refer this official doc- 
  https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels

Comment: I know that the answer lies in channels only but I don't know where to implement the native side of it because its not only flutter but only a feature is in flutter in this case. Rest whole app is in native android.